# How to use pyproj to convert between ITRF2014 2023.9 to ITRF2014 2017.0

Tags: python-3, pyproj, geodesy, pygeodesy

I am trying to convert a current observation from 2023.9 to a ITRF2014 2017.0 epoch. The Longitude Latitude is: -83.9851111, 43.9823026, 191.101.  I Used pyproj to convert to ITRF2014 and then convert 2023.9 data to 2017.0 data.   There was no shift.  I would expect something to move.  Is there a different way I should be using pyproj?

```
from pyproj import Transformer
lon, lat, hgt = -83.9851111, 43.9823026, 191.101 
llh_to_xyz = Transformer.from_crs("+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84", "+proj=geocent +datum=WGS84 +epoch=2023.9")
print(llh_to_xyz.transform(lon, lat, hgt)) #"+epoch=1988.0"
x,y,z = llh_to_xyz.transform(lon, lat, hgt)

transITRF = Transformer.from_crs("+proj=geocent +datum=WGS84 +epoch=2023.9" , "+proj=geocent +datum=WGS84 +epoch=2017.0")#https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/examples.html#d-transformations-with-time
x2, y2, z2 = transITRF.transform(x,y,z)
print(x2, y2, z2)
print(x2-x, y2-y, z2 -z)
```

**RESULT**

```
(481703.2274592639, -4571671.860716729, 4406809.602954089)
481703.2274592639 -4571671.860716729 4406809.602954089
0.0 0.0 0.0
```